# Import data from Oracle datawarehouse to SQL Server via SSIS 2008

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an Oracle datawarehouse, which contains a huge amount of data (around 11 million rows) and want to extract this data on a daily basis to SQL Server database.

[SSIS Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPvpa.jpg)

I have created a package to import data from Oracle to SQL Server using slowly changing dimensions however it is handling around 600 rows per second.

I need my package to just insert new records without updating or doing anything to old records as the data is huge.

Is there any way to do it very fast with any other data flow items?

Comment: We use Attunity Oracle connectors for SSIS instead of standard OleDb.Try them and see if performance is increased:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44582

Comment: Also, maybe you should try a `lookup` on the MSSQL destination table and redirect the no matching rows to the destination table

Comment: Or you can copy all the rows from Oracle to an Staging table in MSSQL and insert from that staging table.

Comment: @vercelli I tried to use lookup but it was giving some error like unable to retrieve code page info from data source....
i have changed default code page property to true but still it shows error.

Comment: Try with Attunity's connector and see if you also get that error

Comment: ok will try and see that. Keep you posted if any error comes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to utilize a Merge Join in SSIS, this should allow for a comparison where only new records are inserted. Also, I don't like using just datetime when determining what data does and does not get inserted, I guess it depends on your source data though. Sounds like there is not a sequential ID field for the Oracle source data? If there is, I'd utilize that and datetime in combination for what data to insert. This could be done in SQL or SSIS.

Comment: yes i have a key column which is a primary key and unique, kindly provide some steps

Answer (score 0):

600/sec is not too bad in your case.
If assume that those 11 millions were collected during only 1 year. That means the number of new records is just 30K per day. Which is about 1 minute to run.

The biggest problem is to identify records to insert.
If you have to have Timestamp or sequential ID to identify latest inserted records.

In case your ID is not sequential you can try to extract into SSIS ONLY ID field from Oracle table and compare it to the existing dataset and then request from Oracle only newest records.

If you don't have these fields you can extract all 11 million records, then generate hash on both sides and compare these hash values to know what new to insert.

Comment: I have a timestamp filed on source side so after initial load do I need to write a query to pull specific data?

Comment: You have to extract MAX timestamp value every time you want to upload data and then extract only records between old a new values. then store the new value for the next time.